# Scroll Two Html Div's Together

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am developing web interface using HTML,CSS,JavaScript to play videos. On video playing div I have added another div using css z-index,  to add play, pause buttons.

When I scroll the web page only video playing div is going up & down.How can I scroll both divs together.

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 1):

kindly check if;

- YOU didn't position:fixed in your CSS file
- you did end all tags properly
- Lastly, make sure the below z-index is given a lower number value.